# Visual Studio 2012 - Fill message test result

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, testing

When a test end its running i have a list like this

```
Result1 Name:   01- AutoGenerateRequest (requestgenerationtest) 
Result1 Outcome:    Passed  
Result1 Duration:   0:00:26,2924949  
Result1 Message: 
Result1 StackTrace:
```

how can i write something in the result message or stacktrace?

Comment: It depends on the test framework you are using. If you are using MSTest, then you can just do `Console.WriteLine` or `Debug.WriteLine`. XUnit removed the ability to do it so its much harder, and I'm not sure if NUnit allows it.

Comment: I have added a Unit Test Project from Visual Studio templates in the framework 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this solution

considering the TestContext that i have in my .cs file

```
private TestContext testContextInstance;
public TestContext TestContext
{
  get { return testContextInstance; }
  set { testContextInstance = value; }
}
```

i used this method

```
TestContext.WriteLine("message");
```

So in my output i see the message that i log.